# How to change the Real user ID of a process from root

Tags: c, process, kernel, freebsd

I have been trying to swap the IDs' of a process to test my program,I could easily set the effectiveUID/UGID of that process by simply calling

```
if (setegid(gid)==0)
    {
        if (seteuid(uid)==0)
        {
        }
    }
```

And then I wanna switch my realUID with the given say 7052 and the EffectiveUID to root(0)

```
if (setregid(egid,rgid)== 0) //egid(7052),rgid(0)
    {
        if (setreuid(euid,ruid) == 0)
        {
        }
     }
```

the `setregid` doesn't work it returns error saying "operations not permitted" I am on FreeBSD,It works fine for debian and other linux distributions can I get some help here?

Comment: real uid/gid is a first parameter and effective is second. I think this is a problem.

Comment: @BorisT I thought so too but they are simply IDs, i just wanna set the EUID of the process as a realUID and RUID of the process as effective UID which means I  want root as an effective user and the real is a normal user. like what they have for Passwd exe where a realUID is not a root but effective becomes root to access password files.

Comment: has your program the suid flag? like passwd?

Comment: @Hayt No, but I setup that as well by "chmod 4755 Myexe" then it has S bit enabled but still the same.

Comment: have you changed the owner of your file to root?

Comment: I am not sure if you need `setreuid` after that anyway. AFAIK the suid bit makes it like your program runs as root even when you are not root (as long as the program is owned by root)

Comment: I think yes because when making this exe I gave "sudo make" then it obviously become root as a file owner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124535/discussion-between-fallingfrombed-and-hayt).

Comment: @Hayt the thing is I shouldn't externally set those stuff it should be done via program ,i just set it for test.

Comment: are you sure passwd works like that? If you can get that "simply" root access this would make linux really insecure. So you get "operations not permitted" maybe just because your user has not the rights to become root.

Comment: @Hayt yes I am sure thats the way it works and many people talked about this way of working in SO and others,And I am running my EXE  with sudo, so it should change its ID somehow thats what been happening in other Linux distributions.

Comment: @Hayt from BSD forum "The real user ID is the UID who owns or starts the process. The effective UID is the user ID the process runs as. As an example, passwd(1) runs with the real user ID when a user changes their password. However, in order to update the password database, the command runs as the effective ID of the root user. This allows users to change their passwords without seeing a Permission Denied error."

Comment: I don't have the passwd source code accessible in the moment to check if it uses those functions. You could have a look in there how it is done. I have found that though: http://www.linuxnix.com/suid-set-suid-linuxunix/

Comment: @Hayt Thanks! I will have a look.

Comment: Nothing much bigger about the SUID handle in the Passwd i've looked at this source code.https://fedorahosted.org/passwd/browser/passwd.c

Answer (score 0):

Changing credentials - this includes GIDs - requires privilege.  And you're dropping this privilege just a few lines above, with seteuid().